# Call __iadd__ in case of non-existence of __add__ in python object?

Tags: python, methods, operator-overloading

I know that, if an object `obj` has the method `__add__` but don't have `__iadd__`, then

```py
obj = obj + other  # Works, obj.__add__(other) is called
obj += other       # Works, try to call obj.__iadd__(other)
                   #   then obj.__add__(other) is called
```

**Question:** What about the reverse? Is there a way to, in case of `__add__` doesn't exist, create a copy, and call `__iadd__` on this copy, without implementing the function `__add__`?

**Description:**
I will use this example with a number to explain my question, only the structure matters.

```py
class MyInteger:

    def __init__(self, number: int):
        self.internal = number

    def __add__(self, other: int):
        return self.__class__(self.internal + other)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.internal)

myinteger = MyInteger(1)
print(myinteger, id(myinteger))  # 1 2614144923680

myinteger = myinteger + 1
print(myinteger, id(myinteger))  # 2 2614144921856

myinteger += 1
print(myinteger, id(myinteger))  # 3 2614144923680
```

We see that `id(#2) != id(#3)`, The operation `+=` creates a new object instead of modifying the one that already exists.

To avoid creating a new object whenever `+=` is called, I can change the method `__add__` to `__iadd__`, but doing so breaks the operation `myinteger = myinteger + 1`, which still should create a new object:

```py
class MyInteger:

    # ...

    def __iadd__(self, other: int):
        self.internal += other
        return self
    
    # ...

myinteger = MyInteger(1)
print(myinteger, id(myinteger))  # 1 2302027888624

myinteger += 1
print(myinteger, id(myinteger))  # 2 2302027888624

myinteger = myinteger + 1  # TypeError
```

**Disclaimer:** My class is not a number, but a structure which must have `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `|` and `&` operations. I came with `MyInteger` only as example

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just implement both methods?

Comment: @user2357112 Reuse the code and avoid copy+paste